# CSS Set Bootstrap Item Active

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following links

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="link1.html" class="list-group-item" id="Home">Link1</a>
    <a href="link2.html" class="list-group-item">Link2</a>
    <a href="link3.html" class="list-group-item">Link3</a>        
</div>
```

I can set an item to be active using this code:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item **active**">Link1</a>
```

However, I want to make it so the links are set to be "active" at the bottom of the page load. What is the proper CSS or JScript to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way is to use the identifier and put your code inside the `ready` function, check examples bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

### Javascript Snippet :

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var home_link = document.getElementById('Home');
    home_link.className = home_link.className+' active';
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="link1.html" class="list-group-item" id="Home">Link1</a>
  <a href="link2.html" class="list-group-item">Link2</a>
  <a href="link3.html" class="list-group-item">Link3</a>        
</div>
```

---

### Jquery snippet :

```js
$(function(){
  $('#Home').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active{
   color: green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="link1.html" class="list-group-item" id="Home">Link1</a>
  <a href="link2.html" class="list-group-item">Link2</a>
  <a href="link3.html" class="list-group-item">Link3</a>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('load', function(){
        $('.list-group-item').first().addClass('active')
    })
)};
```

This will give the first element the class 'active'

**NOTE:** this approach requires jQuery to be loaded.

**If you don't use jQuery you can do:**

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('Home').className = 'active';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one line solution using `jQuery` here is the solution for that:

```
$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
```